# Reboot ec2 after halting of 30 seconds

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2

Is it possible to reboot Ubuntu after 30 seconds?

When I reboot, it should halt then after 30 seconds it should boot.

In case of Amazon aws ec2 instance, waiting for 30 seconds will make it boot with different IP address automatically.

I don't want to pay for elastic ip. Ephemeral ip's are free. Moreover my ec2's are up only for an hour or so. So I don't want to pay for elastic ips for the rest of the hours.

Comment: If you want your instance to keep its IP address between stop/starts, attach an Elastic IP to it.

Comment: @ceejayoz I've updated it

Comment: If you don't care about the Elastic IP why do you care whether the IP address changes?